# How to deploy EJB directly on specific cluster of glassfish from NetBeans

Tags: deployment, glassfish, ejb, cluster-computing

I have two clusters created on my local glassfish server. One is used for war deployment and the other is for ejb deployment.

When i try to deploy the ejb or war directly from netbeans, by default it deploys to the default cluster called "server".

I want to change it, so that it directly gets deployed to the corresponding cluster. How do i accomplish this? A guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this command:

```
asadmin deploy --target <clusterName> <yourApplication>
```

Have a look at this guide (valid for GlassFish 3.1): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkybx.html

Comment: I was looking at that page just before I saw this question on stack. They make it kind of confusing by including the "--virtualservers" parameter. Do you know if that is a required parameter, optional, and what it is for?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a guide for that.  There is a short [blog about registering a cluster as a deployment target in NetBeans](https://blogs.oracle.com/vkraemer/entry/prototype_of_cluster_and_instance).

Once your deployment target is registered, you would use it like a normal instance and chose it as a project's 'target server'.